# Speed up environment configuration for new programmers

Tags: java, docker, jakarta-ee

Im looking for the best solution to help new programmers who are joining our team.
We are developing Java EE application, using Tomcat, Weblogic. 
The problem is that for new programmers configuration takes a lot of time, so we would like to speed up this process.
We were thinking about Docker, but we don't know if this is the best idea.
Do you have any propositions?

Answer (score -1):

You can consider using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to create your development environment either using virtual machines or docker.